# Different confidence intervals when using R and calculating manually

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval

I'm calculating confidence intervals for the dataset below and am using two methods: (1) following R code I found online and (2) manually.

R version:

```
data <- c(187, 181, 178, 188, 173, 179, 177, 172, 187, 193, 189, 183, 169, 179, 173, 175, 174, 183, 175, 172, 167, 189, 183)

x <- mean(data)
n <- length(data)
s <- sd(data)
margin <- qt(0.8,df=n-1)*s/sqrt(n)
low <-  x - margin
high <- x + margin

low
high
```

The results are: (178.109, 180.6736)

Manually:

I transform the one sample t-Student test formula:

```
t = (x - u)/(s/sqrt[n]) 

u = x + t*(s/sqrt[n])

u = 179.3913 + 1.32124*(7.165188/4.795832)
```

where x = mean, u = theoretical mean, s = standard deviation, n = number of observations, t = critical value at 80%.

The results are: (177.4173, 181,3653)

The CI calculated with both methods differ. However, the CI at 90% calculated by R are identical with those calculated manually at 80%. I suppose it's all affected by differences in underlying critical value tables. On the other hand, can the differences be so big? 80–90% CI identical depending on method? Any explanations? Thanks!

Comment: show how you got the result (177.4173, 181,3653)

Comment: `t.test(data,conf.level = 0.80)` gives your result. Extract the confidence interval with `t.test(data,conf.level = 0.80)$conf.int`.

Comment: how did you get 1.714 at 80%?

Comment: `alpha <- 0.2`
`x + qt(p = 1 - alpha / 2, df = n - 1) * s / sqrt(n)`
`x - qt(p = 1 - alpha / 2, df = n - 1) * s / sqrt(n)`

Comment: Sorry, it should be 1.32124 at 80%. It was taken from t-test critical value table. The 1.71714 value is for 90%.

Comment: @RuiBarradas this returns the same values as manual approach.

Comment: @YuriySaraykin's answer is right, doesn't it solve the problem?

Comment: I want to understand how it's possible that two methods return exactly same results at 80/90%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When alpha == 0.2 then:

```
qt(p = 1 - alpha / 2, df = n - 1)
```

is used to calculate the 80% CI and the resulting CI is (177.4173, 181,3653). However, you used:

```
qt(0.8, df = n - 1)
```

to calculate  the margin resulting in (178.109, 180.6736). However, this is actually the 60% CI since solving 0.8 = 1 - alpha / 2 yields alpha = 0.4 and (1 - alpha) * 100% = 60%. You can check this by running:

```
t.test(data, conf.level = 0.6)
```

When alpha == 0.1 the 90% CI is (176.8258, 181.9568) and you can check by running:

```
t.test(data, conf.level = 0.9)
```

The corresponding critical value to the 90% CI is:

```
qt(1 - 0.1 / 2, df = n-1)
```

which is == 1.717144. You can also find this value from t-table [link](https://www.usu.edu/math/cfairbourn/Stat2300/t-table.pdf). When df = 22 then t_0.05 = 1.717.